# How can I find the value of a constraint using Keep Layout

Tags: ios, layout, constraints, keeplayout

I have an object which is constrained.

Is there anyway that I can use keep layout to find out the constraints of that object? Like below:

```
if (userTableView.keepLeftInset.equal == KeepRequired(0)) {

}
else {

}
```

I want to use it to act as a flag for animating the view in and out of view. If the screen is inset to the left then animate on button click, else animate it back.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to figure it out:

```
if (userTableView.keepLeftInset.equal.value == 0) {

}
```

Will calculate the value of the Keep Layout restraint currently

Comment: If anyone has enough reputation a keeplayout tag would be really convenient

Comment: Please note that there were changes in `KeepValue` implementation and you should now compare to `0 +keepRequired` or `KeepRequired(0)` as in your question. If you want to ignore the priority, cast it: `((double)equal == 0)`.

Answer (score 0):

Might be you can fetch all the layout constraints -

```
NSLayoutConstraint *constraints = self.view.constraints;
```